# How to search multiple files for a specific string one by one based on partial name

Tags: find, for

I'll try to explain my problem as best as I can, but please pardon my English ..

What I'm trying to do, seemed simple enough to me, however every solution I've found so far just won't work.

I wanna create a shell script that "reviews" every file in a directory based on a partial name, then check if each file found contains a specific string, and if so, return 1 or 0.

The code I tried so far:
[image]

dont mind the #note

Comment: `find /home/it21704/labs_team/ -type f -name "*somefilename*" -exec grep -c 'somestring'  {} +`

Will return the count of found string in files.  Also don't post screenshots, rather paste code you were trying to achieven the goal.

Comment: so you would like to grep a partial string in all files...am i right?

Comment: that is correct yes @msp9011

Comment: `'$name'` will output literal `$name`. Better use `"$name"` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This should output files which names match `*$name*` and including  `pattern`:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar # needed to be able to use **
grep -l "pattern" **/*"$name"*
```

You can disable globstar afterwards again if you wish:

```
shopt -u globstar
```

---

Alternative using `find`:

```
find . -name "*$name*" -exec grep -l "pattern" {} \;
```